# How to pass JSON on a GET URL with Spring Webclient

Tags: spring, spring-webclient

I need to call an external service with URL that looks like this...

GET [https://api.staging.xxxx.com/locations?where={"account":"bob"}](https://api.staging.xxxx.com/locations?where=%7B%22account%22:%22bob%22%7D)

This is not my service and I have no influence over it, and my codebase at the moment is using Spring WebClient.

```
WebClient.create("https://api.staging.xxxx.com/")
.get()
.uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("locations?where={'account':'bob'}").build())
```

Since WebClient sees the { bracket it tries to inject a value into the URL, which I don't want.

Can anyone suggest how I can do with with Spring WebClient?

Otherwise I will revert to OKHttp or another basic client to sent this request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [UriUtils#encodeQueryParams](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriUtils.html#encodeQueryParams-org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap-) to encode the JSON param:

```java
String whereParam = "{\"account\":\"bob\"}";

 //...
uriBuilder
   .path("locations")
   .queryParam("where", UriUtils.encodeQueryParam(whereParam, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
   .build()
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is to manually url encode the values before passing them to the uri builder.

Also I think that you should use `queryParam()` to specify query parameters.

```
uriBuilder -> 
  uriBuilder.path("locations")
            .queryParam("where", "%7B'account':%20'bob'%7D")
            .build()
```

Another option would be to configure the encoding mode when creating the WebClient

```java
 DefaultUriBuilderFactory factory = new DefaultUriBuilderFactory();
 factory.setEncodingMode(DefaultUriBuilderFactory.EncodingMode.NONE);
 WebClient.builder().uriBuilderFactory(factory).build();
```